# iOS 10 - UICollectionView in UITableViewCell not appearing till tap

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, ios10

I've UICollectionView inside UITableView that only present photos.

it works fine on iOS 9

But in iOS 10, photos not appearing until I tap on cell that holds collection view.
I tried **setPrefetchingEnabled = NO** but still not appearing

any suggestion?

Thank you

Comment: You might check to make sure you're on the main thread when setting the image. Any UI work needs to be on main thread.

Comment: sure I did, I call reloadData and set image on main thread, works fine on iOS 9